# Can't TAKEOWN on C: on Admin account

Tags: windows-7

When I run the following command prompts to get ownership of all files on my disc on my admin account:

```
TAKEOWN /A /F C:
```

and

```
TAKEOWN /F C:
```

I get the error message:

"ERROR: The current logged on user does not have administrative privileges"

How do I fix this? I need full permissions to delete a folder that is giving me "access denied" and I feel like I'm running in circles here.

Comment: have you started the command prompt with elevation(aka run as admin)? http://superuser.com/a/392401/4377

Answer (score 9):

Make sure your command prompt is elevated, otherwise it won't have admin rights even though you are an "admin".

To open an elevated command prompt, search for cmd in your start menu and press <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>ENTER</kbd> or right click on it and choose Run as administrator.

Confirm it is elevated by looking for "Administrator:" prefixed to the window title.

[image: Admin prefix CMD]

Comment: Fantastic! Thank you! Generally speaking, is the takeown command a good workaround if Windows isn't letting an admin account receive full permissions?

Comment: @Joshpho, Good question, I think you should put that as a standalone question.